# How to fix "Cannot connect to server" exception?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was setting up chromedriver with selenium, using the test script provided on the chromdriver website. Everything worked fine, until I switched to a different WiFi network. Now I'm getting an error message when running my script.

I have searched the web for solutions, and I've tried the following things:

- Made sure the chromedriver version matches my chrome version.
- Try to whitelist the ip-address
- I checked for 127.0.0.1 localhost in /etc/hosts

The test code I'm running (/path/to/my/chromedriver is correct):

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/my/chromedriver")  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

I'm expecting the program to run fine, and the browser should pop up. However, the browser is not popping up and I'm getting the following error message:

File "test.py", line 4, in 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/my/chromedriver")  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in **init**
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 104, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /path/to/my/chromedriver

When running the chromedriver in the terminal I'm getting the following message (and the browser is also not popping up as supposed to):

Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.

EDIT: I have the same problem with the geckodriver for firefox, so it is not specific for Chrome.

Comment: The message in the terminal is an informational message, not an error. It is simply saying, "Hey, you're now running an HTTP server on your machine, and a malicious actor could conceivably exploit that, even to take control of a browser session on your machine, so be careful, and protect the ports we're using."

Comment: So how come the browser does not pop-up anymore and the test program gives me an error? In other words, how do I get it to work again?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I also know the thing you've provided in your title and your mentioning of it in your question aren't the cause of it. It sounds like you suspect that to be one of the causes of the issue, and it almost certainly isn't. Since I'm not actually providing an answer to your question, I thought it better to comment, so you could potentially edit the question to prevent others from being confused.

Comment: Alright, in that case I will rephrase question. Thanks.